# why use fflush after printf when printf can print by itself?

Tags: c, flush, stdio, fflush

I'm new to C, sorry if my question is too basic.I often see code like:

```
printf("%d", counter);
fflush(stdout);
```

my guess is that it won't print output if the buffer is not full therefore you need to flush the `stdout`. But I tried to not use `fflush`, only `printf`, I still have out put printed on the screen, then what's the point to use `flush`?

Comment: Did the program exit shortly after this code? Open handles are all flushed when closed, including when the program exits, and the output would appear. `fflush` matters when the program isn't going to exit soon, and you might need the output on the screen *now*, e.g. to display a countdown (that you repeatedly erase with `\r` and print over to update), or to ensure data is sent to a pipe that a parallel process is relying on (especially if you're going to be waiting on a response to said data; if you block without flushing, it nevers sees the data, never responds, and you're deadlocked).

Comment: I tried not looking both ways before crossing the street and it worked just fine, so why do people look both ways before crossing the street?

Comment: @dukeforever: What does that have to do with anything? The OP is using `stdout`, which is neither an input, nor an update stream, it's pure output.

Comment: You have a subtle error in your logic slowjams; or, maybe just an error in your wording.  You think that the buffer only gets flushed when it is full.  That's not completely true.  Yes, a full buffer will trigger a flush; but, it's not the only thing that will trigger a flush.  Longer times in the buffer, and amount of spare compute / io capacity will also case buffers to flush, even when they aren't full.

Comment: @EdwinBuck will new line `\n` also trigger a buffer flush?

Comment: @slowjams There is nothing guaranteed to trigger a buffer flush except `fflush`.  Everything else might trigger one; but, there is no guarantee.  Some streams flush automatically when written to (in some languages).  Typically these are your error streams, not your typical output streams; but, you need to consult the language documentation to really be sure it's guaranteed

Comment: Related: [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/12149471)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main reason to use `fflush` after `printf` is timing.

`printf` will display the information, at some point in time.  Basically all prints to `printf` are buffered.  `fflush` guarantees the buffer is emptied, meaning the print happened at the line of code that called `fflush`.

In programs that tend to crash, `fflush` can be a very useful tool.  Often the message that a user of your program wishes to receive is the last message printed just before the crash.  If the program doesn't have a `fflush` that user will probably not get the last print statement, with the statement being lost in the buffer before display.

This can often lead to developers looking in the wrong place in a program's source code for  errors upon analyzing log files after a crash.  The mental process is "well, it couldn't have made it here, because there's a `printf` we would have seen" when the reality is the program passed the "would have been seen" `printf` statement but died with that message in the buffer.  If one flushes statements just after printing them, this doesn't happen (although the program runs slower, because flushing takes time).

Comment: It may also be worth noting that, by default, `stderr` is not buffered. Therefore, the described problem only exists with `stdout` and not `stderr`.